# Can experience of a division go up from a template change?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I've noticed that if I add troops or support companies to a division template their experience will go down (which makes sense because fresh recruits).

So then does the experience of the division go up if I remove troops from the division template?

Answer (score 1):

It should not. Just did a test, even if you have a missing equipment, say you add tanks to a template and you dont have a single one, you train your units, remove the tanks, but the amount of exp stays the same as it is already accounted for missing equipment.

I can imagine there are bugs or rounding issues (79% could be in reality 80.0d which is stored as 79.99999999 and once it is updated when you change a template it is stored as 80.000000001) and a famous army merging exploit.